# Conditional replaceing with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, replace

I wish to run a regular expression on a list of HTML links, and remove all the target attributes. Then, if the href points to a PDF document, I want to add a target attribute with a value of "_blank"

Here is a link to my attempt so far http://regexr.com/?385g4 (for some reason the opening brackets keep changing to '&lt ;' when I save. You may need to change these for my attempt to work

As you can see, the target attributes have been removed, and i have added new target attributes to all results. What I can't do is only add the target attribute to links to PDFs. I suspect the solution has something to do with lookarounds, but my knowledge of regular expressions is not that great.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Something like this `<a(?: target="(?:.*?)")? href="(.*?.pdf)"(?: target="(?:.*?)")?>(.*?)</a>`? The regex is going to mess thing up when there are more than 2 `<a>` tag on the same line and not all of them are pdf, though.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, It is very likely I will have two links on the same line, and they may be a mix of PDFs and other pages

Comment: If you want a rigid solution, I suggest you get a parser to do the job. I can write a more rigid solution, but it would become an unmaintainable mess for you.

Comment: Using regex for Markup-Data is seldomly the right solution. Load the document into a HTML-Parser, then you can loop through all Links, edit the contents to your liking and get the resulting HTML back from the parser. It's the same with XML, never understood why people poke around in XML with regex... :P